# Porting software / firmware from one architecture to another confusion

Tags: compilation, arm, embedded, u-boot, powerpc

When there is a mention of software / firmware that has been ported to a certain architecture from another, I still struggle with the concept exactly.

If software has been ported to the ARM architecture for example, if this is C/C++ code, my understanding is that the source code doesn't need to change and we just use the ARM specific compiler to compile the code into instructions understood by the ARM chip?

If the source code needs to change depending on the architecture (whether it's ARM, PowerPC, X86 etc.) could you give me an example of why?

I've been reading about U-Boot and it states that it started out as a bootloader for embedded PowerPC chips and since then it got ported to ARM and other architectures. 
Again, would being ported mean that it simply got compiled with a different compiler? I'm almost certain that it is not as simple as that, so please explain what would need to change in the source code etc. to suit a particular architecture.

Comment: This question is too broad. There is a long list of things that may be non-portable, namely everything called implementation-defined behavior in the C standard. Variable sizes and alignment in particular. Depending on the skill and care of the original programmer, you may or may not need changes.  On top of that, things beyond the standard, such as memory mapping, endianess etc. Some things cannot be done in C but has to be carried out in non-portable assembler - most notably the initial parts of the "crt" (C run-time) executed before your application is launched.

Comment: While the code _syntax_ may be portable, the hardware platform differs.  Hardware specific code may require porting.  Other architectural issues may also require modifications.  Byte order for example.  Just being able to compile does not mean the code will run.  A common approach is to have a _hardware abstraction layer_ to separate platform dependent code from platform independent code.

Comment: if using a high level language the architecture mostly goes away, when dealing with interrupts or such sure, but most of the work is talking to the peripherals which are chip/board specific and often have nothing to do with the processor core architecture.  Saying that high level things like linux and u-boot which have abstraction layers to hide much of the details, there is the generic stuff that can simply be re-compiled and the stuff you have to port which is below that abstraction layer, the specific uart, or spi controller. or usb, ethernet, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for a few examples here are two relatively simple non-portable examples in `C`, just to start off.

(Do note that these are examples of non-portable *code*. Porting activities may also include tasks not related to existing code, like writing an interface or a new hardware abstraction layer for a custom target/processor)

1. `sizeof(uint32_t)`
   Easy to expect this evaluates to `4`, but, on architectures like [TI C2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments_TMS320#C2000_series), this evaluates to `2`. An algorithm assuming `4` (which of course is buggy in the first place) *will* compile fine for C2000 and may run as well, but, is highly doubtful if will produce the expected results
2. `Typecasts`

   ```
   typedef struct _M {
     uint32_t a;
     uint32_t b;
   } M;

   uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)malloc(100);

   M *m = (M *)p;

   printf("%d", m->b); //may cause hard fault at m->b on Cortex-M0
   ```

   The last line will always work on a Cortex-M4, but, *may* cause a hard-fault on a Cortex-M0 depending on `p`'s alignment to a 32-bit boundary. See [this](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP36-C.+Do+not+cast+pointers+into+more+strictly+aligned+pointer+types)

Comment: This is the kind of example I was looking or . Thanks